# Authed.io check if user expired or not |VB|

Tags: vb.net

i want the project to check if the period of the account is over or not because it logs in every account even if the period of the account is over but i don't know what is wrong here

```
Imports Authed
Imports Jose.jwe
Imports Newtonsoft
Public Class Form1
Dim auth As Auth = New Auth()
Dim appauth As Boolean = auth.Authenticate("*****************")
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (appauth = False) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Failed Auth")
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Dim login As Boolean = auth.Login(txtLogin.Text, txtPass.Text)
    If login = auth.user.expired Then
        MessageBox.Show("Expired")
        Close()
    End If
    If (login = True) Then
        Me.Hide()
        Form3.Show()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Failed")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There is 1 different option to determine if the user is expired or not.

There is `auth.user.expires` which gives you the exact date when the account is gonna expire. Now you can call `DateTime.Now` and check if the given date from `auth.user.expires` has passed and notify the user that it has expired.